# angular 4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, I met such problem:

When I put an ngIf in the element,

```
 <input type="text" *ngIf="true" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="name" #name="ngModel" />
aaaaaa {{name.dirty}}
```

I got

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PrepareInvestmentComponent.html:1)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13105)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
```

But, when I remove the ngIf, it works fine.
Can I know why and any sign to fix this issue?

Comment: Show us your "name" object

Comment: can you try to add your ngIf condition before checking name.dirty?

Comment: @LeoR name is a simple string

Comment: Ok, you try to access object property, if you have an object called "name" with an atribute called "dirty", so if "name" is just a string, what do you want to do with name.dirty ?

Comment: @gaurav it works if I use <ng-container *ngIf> to wrap these 2 line code, but my logic to check the dirty is far away from the input element in my real project file. I have to put the ngIf inside the input

Comment: @LeoR I want to get if user changed the input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems angular does not allow you to work with reference variable + `*ngIf`...the solution is to use either `ng-container` or just a `div`

like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48763586-rsrtsa?file=app/app.component.html

There's an issue open which seems related to your situation: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13974

Comment: I did not tried but seems you are right as you are cheking undefined

Comment: but, I want to get the dirty value. in this solution, I cannot see the exception, however, I cannot get dirty value.

Comment: I've updated the answer...you just need to use as described on docs

Comment: @ElmerDantas I cannot see the exception but I cannot get the dirty value as well when user modify the input value

Comment: could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ElmerDantas I want to show inputs according to user selected mode, but I still want to know if the user changes the value or not for each showing inputs.

Comment: @ElmerDantas If I use <ng-container ngIf=true> <input .. /> {{name.dirty}}</ng-container>, it work fine

Comment: I've updated the answer...I would say that's my last thought about this issue.  Hope that helps. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the input element is dirty or not try this

```
<input type="text"  id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required 
[(ngModel)]="name" #n="ngModel" />
<p *ngIf="n.dirty">{{n.dirty}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asigning `#name="ngModel"`. Template variables are like identifiers for the elements. You don't have any asignment for them. Also you already have a name defined in you component as you are using it in you `[(ngModel)]` definition.

Also you'll get access to the `dirty` when using `ReactiveForms`. Take a look to this snippet. That works as you might expect.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48763586

Comment: this is an example in https://angular.io/guide/form-validation  I just add a ngIf